# Apple Push Notification

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

My Apple Notification sometime received some get failed to reach on device.
Please help me and tell different scenarios when an Apple Notification fails.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by fail? No notification is received ? or the sending fail ? Are you in production environnement ?

Comment: sometime notification dropped not reached to destined device. No notification is received. yes, I am in production

Answer (score 6):

There could be various reasons for push notification not working. This check list can help you find few :
APNS CheckList

- Provider should install the Entrust Secure Server CA root certificate. This allows TLS/SSL to verify the full APNs server cert chain. This root certificate can be downloaded from [Entrust's site](https://www.entrust.net/downloads/binary/entrust_ssl_ca.cer).
- The device token from development environment will not work on production push service. Each pushenvironment will issue a different token for the same device. If an invalid device token is sent to the wrong environment, the push service will see that as an invalid token and discard the notification.
- If you remove your app from your device and then send a push notification to it, you would expect to have the device token rejected, and the invalidated device token should appear on the feedback service. However, if this was the last push-enabled app on the device, it will not show up in the feedback service. This is because deleting the last app tears down the persistent connection to the push service before the notice of the deletion can be sent.
- Push providers are often behind firewalls. To send notifications, you will need to have TCP port 2195 open. To reach the feedback service, you will need to have TCP port 2196 open. Devices connecting to the push service over Wi-Fi will need to have TCP port 5223 open.
- The IP address range for the push service is subject to change; the expectation is that providers will connect by hostname rather than IP address. However, the entire 17.0.0.0/8 address block is assigned to Apple, so you can specify that range in your firewall rules.
- We can enable APNS logging, install the configuration profile APNsLogging.mobileconfig on device by either putting the file on a web server and downloading it location using Safari on your device, or by sending it as an email attachment and opening the attachment in Mail on your device. We can use mdm to push profile.

More details can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Apple explicitly states that notifications are not guaranteed. They can fail for all sorts of reasons. For example, if you send more than one notification to a device before the first one has been delivered, the prior ones are deleted. I seem to remember reading in the documentation somewhere that the sandbox environment occasionally fails to deliver a message so that you can test your failure code.

Comment: Could you please post some link that state the same I have to present it to the client.Thank you very much.

Comment: Start here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html